# "Has many" relation giving empty result

Tags: go, one-to-many, go-gorm

I am trying to define one to many relation with gorm ORM . I have read all the docs over and over again . Could not find a way to do it.

```
func GetUser1(c *gin.Context) {
    var user models.User
    var activities models.UserActivity
    query := DB.Debug().Find(&user, 1).Model(&user).Related(&activities).Error
    if query != nil {
        panic(query)
    }
    c.JSON(200, &user)
}
```

My Models are ..

```
type User struct {
    Id       int64
    Username string
    Password string `json:"-"`
    Email    string `json:",omitempty"`
    UserActivities []UserActivity
}
type UserActivity struct {
    Id         int64
    UserId     int64 `json:"-"`
    ActorId    int64
    CreatedAt  time.Time
}
```

Debug Results are

```
[2015-11-21 22:21:54]  [3.17ms]  SELECT  * FROM `users`  WHERE (`id` = '1')
[2015-11-21 22:21:54]  [1.39ms]  SELECT  * FROM `user_activities`  WHERE (`user_id` = '1')
```

But I am getting null results

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Username": "test1",
    "Email": "test1@friesen.com",
    "UserActivities": null
}
```

All the primary keys and Indexes are right . I have also tried puttin `gorm:"primary_key"` and `sql:"index"` in `UserActivities` no luck so far .
 However if I replace `UserActivities []UserActivity` with `UserActivities UserActivity` then i get only one row which seems to be right but why `UserActivities []UserActivity` giving no results

Answer (score 0):

use gorm built in model gorm.Model so that your not messing up the "ID" constant

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is very simple.

Rather than querying

```
var user models.User
var activities models.UserActivity
query := DB.Debug().Find(&user, 1).Model(&user).Related(&activities).Error
```

just query

```
var user models.User
query := DB.Debug().Find(&user, 1).Model(&user).Related(&user.UserActivities).Error
```